# Vb.net How read only a specific section of a html template file

Tags: vb.net, file-read

I have a HTML template file using placeholders which will be replaced after reading the template file. Based on the conditions in the code, I want to read only a section of the HTML template file.

For example If condition = False ,
I want to ready only the section in the template file, that starts with the placeholder [IFVALUEFALSESection].

Since File.ReadAllText() -- reads all the contents and not the specific section, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code must implement the logic you seek, for example

```
Dim x as New List(Of String)
Dim capturingSection = False

For Each s In File.ReadLines(path)
  If s.Contains("[ENDIFVALUEFALSESection]" Then Exit For
  If capturingSection Then x.Add(s)
  If s.Contains("[IFVALUEFALSESection]" Then capturingSection = True
Next s

'now you have the lines of the section in x
```